# what data can be gathered from a users iphone for user identification

Tags: iphone, ios

I am doing some research about what types of data is (legally) available for me to store in a database to perform checks against if i decide to do a subscription based application.

For instance can my app query for the devices UDID number? then me save that number against the registration of the application.

Comment: Which country are you in as the legal rules will differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS5, the API to obtain the device UDID has been deprecated for privacy reasons. There are efforts to find suitable replacements, however, such as https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5, which uses the MAC address and application  ID to create a unique identifier that is unique only to an individual app on a particular device.

Comment: Okay thanks man. I was just tring to use that UDID API and saw that they had discontinued it.. bit frustrating but thats all good. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: UDID was not removed in iOS 5, it was deprecated.  It is still available in iOS 5 but may be removed in a later iOS.